# Print random strings from a list (multiple times) with no repeats

Tags: python

I want to print random strings from the same list multiple times throughout the program, but without repeating any of the previously printed random strings.

If I had the following:

```
core = 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'

print (random.sample(core[0:], k=2))
print (random.sample(core[0:], k=2))
```

I'd like the outcome to look something like:

```
b, d
c, a
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`random.sample` itself works without replacement, so there is no case of repetition. Get a sample of 4 and slice:

```
randoms = random.sample(core, 4)

print(randoms[:2])
print(randoms[2:])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `shuffle()` from `random`. Then use slicing to extract necessary elements.

```
import random

initial = 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'
l = list(initial)
random.shuffle(l)

print (l[:2])
print (l[2:])
```

Output:

```
['a', 'c']
['b', 'd']
```

Comment: make a deepcopy in case he doesn't want original to change.

Comment: as OP has a tuple, a list creation is needed. But as the tuple elements are characters in this case, I am skipping the deepcopy part here. If tuple elements were something like list, then deepcopy is required